# VB.net Old style table updates

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Beginner: trying to convert a application to a newer framework asp(vb) to MVC model. the existing code is using a lot of old style updates.

Steps are like: 
- Execute the stored procedure
- in the resultset returned either AddNew or Update as rs.AddNew
- set the columns rs("A") = "123" rs("B") = "xyz"
-calling rs.update

Need to know what this type of approach is called? and some links giving a comparison of old and new approaches?

Comment: Not to good of a question, provide some code, what type of object is rs? Most likely that is a Dataset and can be used whether using MVC or Web Forms

Comment: Old approach: stored procedures or creating SQL statements as strings in the code. New approach: Entity Framework.

Comment: Is this using DAO or classic ADO? That's not old, that's positively ancient.